# Always check with SELECT before INSERT?

Tags: mysql, insert, unique-constraint

If I want to `INSERT` a row only if the primary key doesn't yet exist, is it more efficient/simpler to execute `INSERT` directly and ignore the error in the case of duplication, or should i always run `SELECT` to check if it already exists first?

Answer (score 6):

You could use WHERE NOT EXISTS to check new values before insert a new record.

```
INSERT INTO <table>
(
    field1, field2, field3
)
SELECT value1, value2, value3
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM <table>
                  WHERE <pk fields> = <new values>);
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE foo(id int, v1 int, v2 int);
> INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 100,100);
> INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 200, 200);
> ```

This record exists and should not be inserted:

> ```
> INSERT INTO foo (id, v1, v2)
> SELECT 1, 101, 101
> FROM   dual
> WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM foo WHERE id=1);
> ```

This is a new record:

> ```
> INSERT INTO foo (id, v1, v2)
> SELECT 3, 300, 300
> FROM   dual
> WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM foo WHERE id=3);
> ```

The final result:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM foo;
> ```
>
> ```
> id |  v1 |  v2
> -: | --: | --:
>  1 | 100 | 100
>  2 | 200 | 200
>  3 | 300 | 300
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=decba124fc9bd4e15cf75b3e37c504b0)*

Comment: This would be equivalent to doing a `SELECT` then `INSERT` if not exists, just some syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 2):

The best (more efficient option) will depend on the expected probability of PK collision.

If the chance of collision is high, then I'd save the DML overhead and do the `SELECT` first before the potential `INSERT`.

If the chance of collision is rare, then it is likely sufficient to do an `INSERT IGNORE`.

Note: if the PK is an `auto_increment`, a failed `INSERT IGNORE` can potentially inflate the `auto_increment` (see [innodb_autoinc_lock_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode) for variable options).

Comment: Is a **failed** `INSERT` operation costlier than `SELECT`? I was thinking that it could be exactly the same cost because both would involve first looking up the primary key on the table, then exiting immediately (returning the row in the case of `SELECT`)

Comment: In other experiments, it seems that the overhead (network, parsing, locking, etc) for any trivial statement is 90%.  Hence, I suggest `INSERT IGNORE` would be about as fast as a failed `SELECT` and nearly twice as fast as `SELECT + INSERT`.  But, beware of 'burning' an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.

Answer (score 1):

Usually IODKU is the better way:

```
INSERT INTO tbl ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        ....
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: In my case, i want it to ignore the insertion instead of updating.

Comment: @James - What about `INSERT IGNORE ...` ?